# Split out the css commands manually

Tags: css, mobile, navigation

The squarespace template that I am using will not let me insert the code below. I got a response back that I need to split out the commands manually.

I am getting an error back with the background: I had tried a few times to accomplish this but couldn't quite get it accurate.

```
.mobile-nav .show-nav {
background: url("http://www.jobspark.ca/item/517adb63e4b06ea9dd79ace8?format=original")    no-repeat scroll center center / 30% auto #000000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
max-height: 50px;
padding: 1em 40px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely the [CSS 3 background](http://dev.opera.com/static/dstorey/backgrounds/background-shorthand.html) shorthand thats causing the problem, support isn't consistent across all platforms and browsers - you should split the shorthand up like so:

```
.mobile-nav .show-nav {
background-image: url('http://www.jobspark.ca/item/517adb63e4b06ea9dd79ace8?format=original');
background-position: center center;
background-size: 30% auto;
background-color: black;
/* omitted default values */
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
max-height: 50px;
padding: 1em 40px 50px;
}
```